# RYU Controller Block traffic

Tags: openflow, ryu

I am creating a simple network with `mininet`. and i want block traffic from one host to another with controller.I Want know which of RYU API useful for me.`parser."OFPMatch"` or another `RYU API`

Comment: Just install a flow in the switch, and set action like this: `action = ""`. By default, an empty string means block/drop

Answer (score 0):

Something you may find useful for working with the Ryu controller is Ryuretic. It provides an additional layer of abstraction for the Ryu Controller, so all you have to worry with is the incoming packet.

The Ryuretic backend renders all events to the user as a pkt (a dictionary object), and the contents of the pkt are retrieved by providing the header field of interest (e.g, pkt['srcmac'], pkt['dstmac'], pkt['ethtype'], pkt['inport'], pkt['srcip'], etc.) Using the information from the pkt, the user can choose which fields to match and what action (fwd, drop, redirect, mirror, craft) to take when a match is found.

To install Ryuretic, simply copy the [files] (https://github.com/Ryuretic/RyureticLabs/tree/master/ryu/ryu/app/Ryuretic) to the directory /ryu/ryu/app/Ryuretic. If you installed Ryu, then you already have the /ryu/ryu/app directory. You just need to create the Ryuretic directory and copy the files there.

[Ryuretic Labs](https://github.com/Ryuretic/RyureticLabs/wiki) provides setup instruction and some use cases for implementing security features on SDNs using Ryuretic. It also provides a Mininet testbed for testing your network applications on the VM provided by SDN Hub.